# Bash Syntax Error Python Help

Tags: command-line, bash

I am trying to learn about new functions and methods of some classes in python, however when I try to use the help() in terminal, I get this error.

```
morningdew72@saphira:~$ conda activate
(base) morningdew72@saphira:~$ python help(pzybar)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
(base) morningdew72@saphira:~$
```

Am I using this command wrong?
Thanks

Comment: I think you want to type "python", press return and get the interactive python >>> prompt, then type "help(pzybar)".  (I get "pzybar not defined, but then I haven't installed it.)  If you really want to do it all on one line, "python -c 'help(pzybar)'" would do it.

Comment: I had to import pyzbar first, is this normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `pydoc`, followed by the "thing" name. In your case, `pydoc pzybar`.

From `man pydoc`:

> **pydoc2.7**  **name**  Show text documentation on something.  **name** may be the
>   name of a Python keyword, topic, function, module, or package, or a
>          dotted reference to a class or function within a module or module in a package.

You may also use `pydoc3` if you have installed packages for Python3.